# Return Value based on 2 criterias

Tags: excel, criteria

ive noticed that similar question has been answered before but non are what i am looking for.

[image: Sheets and Data]

Sheet 1

```
Site    Program Data Finished       
A1001   B3          
A1001   B5          
A1001   B6          
A1002   B3          
A1003   B6          
A1003   B5
```

Sheet 2

```
Site    Location    Date Released   Program Data Finished
A1001   Chicago 1/3/2018    B6  6/5/2016
A1002   Chicago 1/4/2018    B3  1/3/2018
A1001   Chicago 1/1/2018    B3  4/5/2016
A1001   Chicago 1/2/2018    B5  1/1/2018
A1003   Chicago 1/5/2018    B6  4/5/2016
A1003   Chicago 1/6/2018    B5  1/1/2018
A1004   Chicago 1/7/2018    B4  1/2/2018
```

i need to return the Date Finished Values from Sheet 2 under Date Finished in Sheet 1 based on 2 criterias: the Site and Program.

So look for Site A1001 with B3 program under sheet 2 and return the Date Finish in sheet 1.

i'm stuck.... i have this formula but its not doing the job.

```
=IFNA(IF(VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP($A2290,[Capital Projects.xlsx]Modification'!$D:$D,1,0),'[Capital Projects.xlsx]Modification'!$D:$I,6,0)="5GmmW", VLOOKUP($A2290,[Capital Projects.xlsx]Modification'!$D:$EG,55,0),""),"")
```

Comment: what is wrong with the formula you have?

Comment: @LioraHaydont it looks for only the first value and returns, for example there are 3 sites A1001 but 3 different programs, it only returns the first value and stops looking for the rest of the programs for that site

Comment: " i have this formula but its not doing the job." It's hard to help you if we don't know what error you get. Is it giving you an error message, is it showing you wrong data?

Comment: @LioraHaydont it looks for only the first value and returns, for example there are 3 sites A1001 but 3 different programs, it only returns the first value and stops looking for the rest of the programs for that site , i may be not using the best formula to do what im looking for....

Comment: Why did you remove the ascii table of data from your question?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld its the same as the photo. the photo is formatted correctly so its easier to see the columns

Comment: Yes it is, but how do you copy the photo into a worksheet if you want to reproduce things?  Do you have a special tool for that?

Comment: will the programs and sites be unique? e.g. A1001 and B3 only appear once?

Comment: @SeanC Yes the will be unique

Comment: Thanks for restoring the ASCII table.  By the way, for complicated formatting issues, you can use this [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables).  After copying the table into your question (or answer), select the table and then the **code** `{..}` token

Comment: @RonRosenfeld great info. thank you. i will do this next time

Answer (score 1):

Using structured references, with `Table1` being the table on sheet2:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,4,(Table1[Site]=A2)*(Table1[Program]=B2)*Table1[date finished],1)
```

You can use regular references instead of a Table, but just ensure they cover more than the expected number of rows.

[image]

Comment: Beauty... I forgot about **[`AGGREGATE`](https://support.office.com/article/aggregate-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df)**... I was going to suggest a helper column.

Comment: @ashleedawg No need for helper column.  Without `AGGREGATE` you could also use `MAX` with an array-entered (`CSE`) formula.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld thank you Ron, im getting an error. also i cannot make changes to the raw data by making it a table. its actually pulling data from a sheet on another workbook.

Comment: Then just change the table references into absolute references referring to wherever your data is located.

Comment: With regard to your error, I'm afraid I can't do anything since you don't tell what the error is, and Excel can produce many kinds of errors.  But Excel does have facilities to indicate the cause of various errors.  But you'd have to know the type of error (error message) in order to make use of that.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld i dont know how to attach the error in the comments section, :(

Comment: @RonRosenfeld there is a problem with this formula. not  trying to type a formula? when the first character is an - or minus sign excel thinks its a formula. you type = 1+1, cell shoes: 2, to get around this type '=1+1

Comment: @sara Show the actual formula you are using (copy from the formula bar and paste into a comment), and also note carefully where the cursor is within the formula in the formula bar when you see that error

Comment: @RonRosenfeld  ok so i tried this and it gives me the #Value return. im using two worksheets: =AGGREGATE(14,4,('[Capital Projects.xlsx]L1900'!$D:$D=A8)*('[Capital Projects.xlsx]L1900'!$I:$I=G8)*'[Capital Projects.xlsx]L1900'!$CU:$CU,1)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld i got your first formula to work. i had a type. but i have never used aggregate and so when i try to use btw two worksheets im not sure if im doing it correctly. i keep getting the #Value! error

Comment: @sara I suspect the problem is that, with the whole column references, you are including header rows or other rows with non-numeric data.  This will produce an error when you try to multiply.  You might be able to use the `ignore errors` argument in `AGGREGATE`, or you might have to restrict your references to only those rows that are either empty, or have numeric data.

Comment: @sara A little testing shows that setting the `ignore error values` options in the `AGGREGATE` formula should solve the problem of having textual data in your date column.  And unless you've got `1,000,000` rows, you'll be better off for speed of calculation using range references that are closer to the maximum used range.  Whether this is necessary in your specific situation is unknown to me.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld thank you so much for all your help. i'm stuck one more thing: the same exact table as before but instead of dates the Value under "Date Finished" is either "A" or "P". can i use the same formula? i tried and gave me an error

Comment: @sara No.  If you use small ranges, and the `Evaluate Formula` tool, you will see that the formula works in part by multiplication.  Dates are numbers and can be treated arithmetically.  `A` and `P` are not numbers so cannot be.  You can use a similar function, but would need to compute the appropriate Row number in the array, and then use `INDEX` to return the desired value.  There are examples of doing this on the forum.  Suggest you work on that approach, after first understanding exactly how this formula works.  If you cannot figure it out, suggest you post the issue as a separate problem.